# Multiple solutions in Shorthest Path Algorithm (A*)

Tags: algorithm, path, a-star, short

So the other day I found a website, where I could refresh my knowledge about algorithms and I was bumped into a problem.

What will happen, if I run an A* algorithm on a map, where two - exactly the same - [possible solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfvoO.jpg) are available?

- How the algorithm decides, which solution is the better? Which
  one will be choosen and why?
- If it's random, then is there a way to bring some consistency into it through code (and
  how)?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ruby]?

Comment: All shortest path algorithms identify a single shortest path from given node A to given node B, or conclude that no path exists. (Some produce shortest paths from A to all other nodes in the course of computing a shortest pathfrom A to B.) All those algorithms could be modified to identify all shortest paths from A to B. If you want specifics select one of those algorithms (e.g., [Djikstra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) and post a question asking how it could be modified to produce all shortest paths. (cont.)

Comment: As to which shortest path an algorithm will select, that's purely an implementation issue. The algorithm's author certainly had  no preference; algorithmic efficiency would always be the driver. A simple analogy: suppose one wanted to determine the index of the largest value in the array `arr = [1,4,2,4]`. A common algorithm would be to first choose `0`, then choose `1` because `arr[1] > arr[0], then reject `2` and `3` because neither `arr[2] #=> 2` nor `[arr[3] #=>4` is larger than `4`. One could instead replace the index `1` with `3`, which is slightly less efficient, so what's the point?

Comment: I believe @Jörg's question is [rhetorical](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rhetorical-question?q=+rhetorical+question); he is saying that this question shouldn't have a Ruby tag because it has nothing to do with Ruby. I agree. Also, you should only uses pictures when it is essential to do so, as links have a tendency to break in future.

Comment: Thank you all for those answers, I see it now, how it should work!

The reason behind the 'ruby' tag, that I wanted not only understand, but also implement it in some sort of way, which in this case was Ruby. (how? in my second question kinda aimed this language)

I'm also appriciate all kind of advice about the 'ideal question form', because I'm new on this site and I'm still learning it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it depends on how you implement the algorithm.
It's not random. If you run the algorithm on the same map multiple times, then the same solution is given every time.
It all depends on how you implement the algorithm.

In the example that you've linked, you can implement the algorithm in two ways.
You can make it check the 'up'-direction first, or you can make it check the 'right'-direction first.

I hope this answer helped

Answer (score 0):

If multiple solutions are correct, then it doesn't matter which answer is chosen as neither is better than the other.

An algorithm will always choose the same path provided there is no random element in the algorithm. The traversal should always be in the same order.